# paper.js removeOnDown(); within node.js & socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, canvas, socket.io, paperjs

I use Paper.js 0.9.18 and node socket.io 1.0.6 to build a collaborative board.
At mouse down a .png image will draw in canvas and it's visible for all connected users.
With a second mouse click, a new png image will be drawn to any new position on the canvas (visible for all users) and the first image will be removed simultaneously (but "local" only).

path.removeOnDown();

http://paperjs.org/reference/path/#removeondown

this works fine for the active user on his own canvas only. But the .png image for all other users will not removed. My question is, how does Paper.js's .removeOnDown(); works within node & socket.io? Any ideas? Maybe there are other ways to realize that?

The paper script I use

assets/js/script.js:

```
function onMouseDown(event) {
    var x = event.point.x;
    var y = event.point.y;
    var rotate = ff;
    drawAircraft( x, y, rotate);
    // Pass the data for this position and rotate of the png image
    // to a special function for later
    emitAircraft( x, y, rotate);
} 

function drawAircraft( x, y, rotate ) {
    // Render the circle with Paper.js:
    var raster = new Raster('./assets/img/Black-Aircraft-Icon.png');
    raster.position = [x,y];
    raster.scale(0.2);
    raster.rotate(rotate);
    // Refresh the view, so we always get an update:
    view.draw();
```

> ```
> // Remove the path (raster), next time the mouse is pressed:
> raster.removeOnDown();
> ```

```
}

// An object to describe the aircraft draw data
function emitAircraft( x, y, rotate ) {
    var data = {
        x: x,
        y: y,
        rotate: rotate
    };
    // send a 'drawAircraft' event with data to the server
    socket.emit( 'drawAircraft', data)
    console.log( data )
}

socket.on( 'drawAircraft', function( data ) {
    console.log( data );
    // Draw the circle using the data sent from another user
    drawAircraft( data.x, data.y, data.rotate );
})
```

html:

```
<canvas id="draw" resize="true" keepalive="true"></canvas>
<script src="assets/js/paper-full.js"></script>
<script type="text/paperscript" src="assets/js/script.js" canvas="draw"></script>
```

Thanks to all in advance

Sun